# Hi iwant to send message in whatsapp but my message type in input_box twice

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```py
def send_unsaved_contact_message():
    global message
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
        browser.implicitly_wait(10)
        #input_box = (By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Type a message']")
        #input_box = (By.XPATH,"//div[@class='p3_M1']")
        input_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
        "p[class='selectable-text copyable-text']")))
        pyperclip.copy(message) # get text in clipboard 
        for ch in message:
            if ch == "\n":
                ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).key_up(
                    Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.BACKSPACE).perform()
            else:
                input_box.send_keys(ch)
        input_box.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,"v")
        #browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, elem, text)
        whatsapp_send_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
        "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/footer[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/span[1]")
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", whatsapp_send_button)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to send message exception: ", e)
        return
```

**for example this is my message:**
 Hello everyone
welcome to my group
Group link:
Thank you for visiting our site:

**but send in input message like this:**
� Hello everyone�
welcome to my group
Group link:
Thank you for visiting our site:
 Hello everyone
welcome to my group
Group link:
Thank you for visiting our site:

Comment: Why not to use the much proven and robust `click()` instead of Javascript click?

Comment: You cannot send text to paragraph node. You need to find input node instead

Comment: I used click, but it didn't work, but now it's not a problem at all, it doesn't recognize the part where the message is supposed to be entered

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you guide me more?  @DonnyFlaw

Comment: Your `input_box` point to `p` node. It should be `input` node

Comment: it gives such an error:


Failed to send message exception:  Message:
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:186:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:398:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16 @DonnyFlaw

Comment: I've been stuck on this for a few days now. If you know another way, please help me ٬@DonnyFlaw

Comment: Can you share link or at least HTML-code sample? It's hard to help without seeing the page

Comment: do you mean this? What's the link? @DonnyFlaw

<p class="selectable-text copyable-text" style="" xpath="1"><br></p>

Comment: I get the xpath with the extension and I think it is correct, but I don't know why it gives an error  
@DonnyFlaw

Comment: This `<p class="selectable-text copyable-text" style="" xpath="1"><br></p>` is paragraph node. It contains text. It's not supposed to receive text or Keys via `send_keys`. You need to select another node

Comment: Thank you very much this answered
  Excuse me, I have another question now sending my message but irregular and disrupted what I have to do

@DonnyFlaw

Comment: It's better to create another question with more detailed problem description

Answer (score 0):

you can replace with

```
js_send_text = """
function send_text(text) {
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    dataTransfer.setData('text', text);
    const event = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
          clipboardData: dataTransfer,
          bubbles: true
        });
    let el = document.querySelector('#main .copyable-area [contenteditable="true"][role="textbox"]')
    el.dispatchEvent(event)
}
send_text(arguments[0])
"""

self.driver.execute_script(js_send_text, message)
```

and to check if finish typing can use:

```
            old = ''
        while True:
            element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                               '#main .copyable-area [contenteditable="true"][role="textbox"]')
            if element.text == old:
                break
            sleep(1)
            old = element.text
```

send button:

```
self.driver.execute_script("""document.querySelector('[data-testid="send"]').click()""")
```